# Unity ignores "scale for menu and titlebars"

Tags: unity, resolution, xrandr

Just got Asus Zenbook ux305 with Intel Core M 5300. Resolution 3200x1800 QHD.
Put Ubuntu 14.10 on it. First result, everything is damn small. `xrandr` outputs:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 3200 x 1800, current 3200 x 1800, maximum 3200 x 1800
default connected primary 3200x1800+0+0 0mm x 0mm
  3200x1800      90.0*
```

- Changing resolution to a smaller one doesn't work since it's the only resolution available.
- "scale for menu and titlebars" has absolutely no effect.
- `xrandr --dpi` has no effect
- Screen animations are impossibly slow. Maybe the 3d acceleration doesn't work?

I have the latest `xserver-xorg-video-intel`. What are my options to either make the resolution smaller or make the scaling work?

Comment: is it possible that ubuntu 14.10 (and its xserver-xorg-video-intel) as of today does not support the intel core m hd graphics 5300 ? May installing ubuntu 15.04 solve it? I see that every transition on graphical desktop is  very slow, even after disabling effects in unity.

Answer (score 1):

Work fine for me with the following details:

```
System:    Kernel: 4.4.0-15-generic x86_64 (64 bit)
           Desktop: Unity 7.4.0  Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: ASUSTeK (portable) product: UX305LA v: 1.0
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: UX305LA v: 1.0
           Bios: American Megatrends v: UX305LA.206 date: 08/03/2015
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i7-5500U MHz
Graphics:  Card: Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.1 driver: intel
           Resolution: 3200x1800@60.00hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.1.2
```

By usability reasons I set up the scaling of the screen to 2 - 2.2 at System settings "All settings:Displays - Scale for menu and title bars"

Comment: OP was using 14.10 and They said it worked in 15.04 later (by upgrade). So, this answer isn't much convincing I think

Answer (score 0):

Installing Ubuntu 15.04 (although not oficially released, yet) solves the problem. It seems that the chipset is relatively new and ist not 100% supported by the 14.xx version.